# Error propagation with 3 variables. System of linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, error-propagation

Working on old exams in basic numerical modeling. Need help to check if my solution to a problem with no solution proposal is correct.

Problem:

$x=-\frac{5}{18}a+\frac{1}{18}b+\frac{7}{18}c$

$y=\frac{1}{18}a+\frac{7}{18}b-\frac{5}{18}c$

$z=\frac{7}{18}a-\frac{5}{18}b+\frac{1}{18}c$

Assume $a,b,c$ are correctly rounded, and $\bar E_
a=\bar E_b=\bar E_c=0.005$. Find $\tilde E_x$, $\tilde E_y$ and $\tilde E_z$.

From my computations, $\tilde E_x=\tilde E_y=\tilde E_z=0.00361$. Does this seem right?

Formulas:

[image]

Comment: Formulas inserted.